# Предлог "в"

Tags: стилистика

"С августа 2004 года проходил службу в академии МВД России в должности старшего преподавателя, в которой 16 июля 2007 года уволен на пенсию". Правильно ли употреблен предлог "в" перед словами "должности"и "которой"?

Answer (score 1):

Считаю, что все правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Это канцелярит, да еще военный (полицейский в данном случае), а у него свои законы, лучше не спорить.

В другой ситуации я бы посоветовал "на должности" и "с которой". Впрочем, тогда ещё лучше фразу вообще переделать под "общечеловеческие" нормы.